# ¿Porqué me sale error?

Tags: c, matrices, dev-c++, programación-funcional

[image]

no logro detectar porque me aparece error:( si ya chequé la sintaxis, dice que aun no declaro n pero ya la declare en menu void, igualmente intente declararla dentro de main y no pude, también dice que tengo mal el paréntesis, ¿alguien que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Yo tampoco logro detectar porque te aparece error, no porque entienda tu código si no porque no lo veo. Soy daltónico y me es imposible ver algunos colores en pantalla, es por eso que uso una combinación de colores especial que en tu caso, al ofrecer una captura de pantalla, no tengo. De todas maneras, esta es una página sobre código no sobre capturas de pantalla. Poner una captura de pantalla además de que es más difícil que copiapegar texto, no ayuda en nada porque no puedes compilarla, ni buscar texto ni copiapegar sus caracteres. **PUBLICA CÓDIGO**, **NO CAPTURAS DE PANTALLA**

Comment: Coincido con @PaperBirdMaster: yo no soy daltónico y tampoco veo un pimiento. Bienvenida, Andrea, por cierto. Sobre tu problema; ¿has probado a declarar n? Declararla como int. En la línea superior a la declaración del array, si quieres.

Comment: De acuerdo con los dos comentarios anteriores. Para que te podamos ayudar, mejor copia y pega el código.

Answer (score 0):

como estas?
Tenes unos cuantos errores de conceptos.

1) Al crear una matriz, se tiene que realizar con un numero, o con un valor definido en define, ya que c no admite crear una matriz con un tamaño establecido por una variable.

Para ello deberias crear un vector de punteros y pedir la memoria necesaria a través de la funcion malloc.

[image]

Ahi te dejo una foto acerca del tema que deberias buscar y una breve explicacion.

2) El prototipo de una funcion sirve para "avisarle" al programa que estas implementando una funcion que, en este caso, devuelve void y tenes que pasarle 2 argumentos, 1 matriz y un tipo int.

El programa interpreta esto, y en base a eso compila el programa.
Entonces, si estas utilizando una variable te va a aparecer error porque esto tampoco es posible,

¿Probaste si funciona sacandole la n del prototipo?

3) Entiendo que la funcion

```
void llenarMatrices(int [][],int);
```

lo que deberia realizar es llenar la matriz que creaste dentro de menu, para eso deberias pasarle como argumento la dirección de la matriz, para poder cambiar su valor, ya que de lo contrario estarias pasandole una copia de la misma.
Para entender bien esto podrias buscar más ayuda buscando **Parametros por valor y por referencia**

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda!

Saludos

Comment: En C, es válido usar arreglos con longitud variable (por ejemplo, `int m[][n]`), debido a que, ANSI C lo agregó en C99, sin embargo, no todos los compiladores soportan esa característica y por esa razón, se prohíbe su uso. Para más información: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf (**6.7.5.2 Array
declarators**)

Answer (score 0):

El error de compilación sucede porqué los tipos de cada parámetro del prototipo de la función `llenarMatriz`, no coincide con el encabezado de su respectiva definición.

Tu has declarado la función de esta manera:

```
void llenarMatriz(int m1[][n], int);
```

Pero el problema, es que tienes definida la función de esta forma:

```
void llenarMatriz(int n, int m1[][n])
{
    //code
}
```

Si te das cuenta, el primer parámetro no coincide con el parámetro que has puesto en su declaración/prototipo, es decir, el compilador queda confundido y no sabe si el primer parámetro es una variable de tipo `int` o una simple matriz.

Lo mismo pasa con el segundo parámetro, no coincide con su respectiva definición.

Para arreglar este error, necesitas que los parámetros de la definición y prototipo, coincidan o mejor dicho, que sean equivalente.

Por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void llenarMatriz(int, int m1[][n]);

int main(void) {


    return 0;
}

void llenarMatriz(int n, int m1[][n])
{

}
```

Sin embargo, si compilamos el código de arriba, nos seguirá dando un error y esto se debe porqué el compilador no reconocerá el identificador `n` que esté en el prototipo, por lo tanto, tendrás que agregar el nombre `n` en el primer parámetro de la declaración de dicha función.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void llenarMatriz(int n, int m1[][n]);

int main(void) {


    return 0;
}

void llenarMatriz(int n, int m1[][n])
{

}
```

De este modo, debería de compilar sin errores.

**Observaciones:**

**1.** Si vas a usar los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array) lo debes saber utilizar de forma correcta.

En este ejemplo, aunque no dé un error de compilación en GCC, es incorrecto:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n;
    int m[3][n];
    return 0;
}
```

No tiene sentido crear un arreglo [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) sin que la variable `n` no esté inicializada, así que deberías de corregir ese error en tu código.

**2.** Los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) fueron introducidos [a partir de C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (**6.7.5.2 Array
declarators**), por lo tanto, es válido usar en C un arreglo con longitud variable; sin embargo, no se recomienda su uso, debido a que, es propenso a errores como por ejemplo, el típico [desbordamiento de pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_pila) (sucede expresamente cuando ocurre una recursión infinita o cuando un arreglo tiene un tamaño excesivamente grande), si llegara a ocurrir este error, tu programa dejaría de funcionar al instante y ni sabrás cual fue el error porqué al usar los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) no hay forma de agregar alguna condición que lo detecte y de este modo, no podrás lograr que el programa avise el error.

Una solución segura, es usar memoria dinámica. Debido a que, podemos detectar si hubo alguna falla al momento de asignar memoria con [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

En tu caso, deberías de crear una matriz dinámica y hacer que la función `llenarMatriz` reciba tres parámetros:

- Uno que reciba el tamaño de filas y otro las columnas.
- El tercero deberá de recibir la dirección base (del primer elemento) de un arreglo de punteros, básicamente cada puntero de ese búfer, apuntará a la dirección base de un array dinámico y a esto, es lo que se conoce, como [matriz dinámica](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Matrices_Dinamicas).

Un ejemplo básico de como crear una matriz dinámica, sería de esta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void llenarMatriz(int , int , int** )

int main(void) 
{
    int filas = 10, columnas = 5;
    //Reservamos memoria para el arreglo de punteros
    int** A = malloc(filas*sizeof(int *));
    if(A == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: No se pudo asignar memoria!");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        //Reservamos memoria para cada arreglo dinámico
        A[i] = malloc(columnas*sizeof(int));
        if(A[i] == NULL)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x != i; ++x)
            {
                //Liberamos la memoria que hayamos reservado para las columnas
                free(A[i]);
            }
            //Liberamos la memoria que reservamos para las filas.
            free(A); 
            printf("Error: No se pudo reservar memoria!");
            return 1;
        }
    }   
    llenarMatriz(filas, columnas, A);
    //Liberamos la memoria cuando el programa termine su ejecución
    for (i=0; i<filas; i++)
        free (A[i]);
    free(A);
    return 0;
}

void llenarMatriz(int filas, int column, int** p)
{

}
```

Si te das cuenta, cada vez que uso memoria dinámica, debo liberar la memoria con la función [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/), de este modo, evitamos [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria) (pérdida de memoria).

Otra observación que le podemos dar al código, es cada vez que asignamos memoria, debemos detectar si la función `malloc` pudo reservarlo, de lo contrario, mandamos un mensaje de error.